# Image mathematics inverse image

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\psi:V\rightarrow \psi(V) \subseteq X$ be a map, where $V\subseteq Y$.

Assume $B\subseteq X$ and $\psi^{-1}(B)\subseteq V$. Then, does it follow that $B\subseteq \psi(\psi^{-1}(B))$?

Obviously if $B\subseteq \psi(V)$ then result holds due to surjectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily:

Take $X=B=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=V=\{2\}$ and $\psi\colon V\to X$ given by $\psi(2)=0$. Then $\psi^{-1}(B)=\{2\}$ and thus $\psi(\psi^{-1}(B))=\{0\}\subsetneq B$.